# Heap sort - C programmnig

Tags: c, sorting, structure, heap

I've been having trouble getting my heap sort program to properly sort integers from a read in file. The output current looks like this:

```
Heap created successfully!
size = 10
Insertion
9
8
7
6
3
4
2
5
1
0
Delete
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
0
```

I dont know what is going on with the deletion section (insert seems to work fine) of my code and have been modifying for hours and still can't get it. If anyone could shed some light on this code please do so. I would greatly appreciate it!

```
struct heap_t {
    int last; 
    int size;
    int max;
    int *data;

};

void heapify(struct heap_t *heap_array, int size);
void swap(int i, int min, struct heap_t *heap_array);
void deletion(int i, struct heap_t *heap_array);

enum {INIT = 1, GROW = 2};

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{

    char buf[LEN];
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    int i = 0;

        if (argc != 2) {
        printf("error in input\n");
        printf("usage: ./heap [FILE]\n");
        printf("[FILE] is a list of integers one per line\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        assert(fp);
    }

    struct heap_t *heap = malloc(sizeof(struct heap_t));
    heap->size = INIT;
    heap->max = INIT;
    heap->data = NULL;

    while (fgets(buf, LEN, fp)) {

        /* read in data from file */
        /* assign to heap->data */

        /* grow the array as necessary */
        if (heap->size > heap->max) {
            heap->data = realloc(heap->data, GROW * heap->max *sizeof(int));
            assert(heap->data);
            heap->max = GROW * heap->max;
        }
        else if (heap->data == NULL) {
            heap->data = malloc(INIT * sizeof(int));
            assert(heap->data);
        }
        *(heap->data + i) = atoi(buf);

        /* Heapifys as it inserts, thus building the heap*/
        heapify(heap, i);

        heap->size++;
        i++;
    }   
    printf("\nHeap created successfully!\n");

    /* size is off by one */
    heap->size--;
    printf("size = %d\n", heap->size);

    printf("Insertion\n");
    for (i = 0; i < heap->size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *(heap->data + i));  
    }

    heap->last = (heap->size);

    i = 0;
    while(heap->size){
        deletion(i, heap);
        i++;
    }

    printf("Delete\n");
    for (i = 0; i < heap->size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *(heap->data + i));  
    }


    /* send data to stdin -- if you correctly built a heapsort
         * this will print the data in ascending order */
    /*for (i = 0; i < heap->size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", *(heap->data + i));  
    }*/

    /* cleanup */
    free(heap->data);
    free(heap);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

void heapify(struct heap_t *heap_array, int i)
{
    int child = i, parent = (child - 1) / 2;

    while(child != 0 && *(heap_array->data + child) > *(heap_array->data + parent)){
        swap(child, parent, heap_array);
        child = parent;
        parent = (child - 1) / 2;

        for(j = 0; j < heap_array->size; j++){
            printf("%d, ", *(heap_array->data + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void swap(int child, int parent, struct heap_t *heap_array)
{

    int temp = 0;
    temp = *(heap_array->data + child);
    *(heap_array->data + child) = *(heap_array->data + parent);
    *(heap_array->data + parent) = temp;
}

void deletion(int i, struct heap_t *heap_array)

{

    int temp;
    int j = 0;

    temp = *(heap_array->data + 0);
    *(heap_array->data + 0) = *(heap_array->data + (heap_array->size - 1));
    *(heap_array->data + (heap_array->size)) = temp;

    heap_array->size--;

    for(i = j; j < heap_array->size; j++){
        heapify(heap_array, j);
    }
    printf("%d -", *(heap_array->data + 0));
}
```

Comment: Since the code contains no comments and doesn't make any obvious sense, it's really hard to know how to fix it. For example, `deletion` takes a parameter called `i` which it never uses, and the name "i" gives us no clue what it's supposed to mean. The loop is also puzzling. If you delete from a heap, don't you get a smaller heap? So if `i` is supposed to be which item to remove from the heap, it rapidly gets out of bounds. (Consider a heap with ten items. After you've removed 8 items, you try to remove item 9 -- but a heap with only 2 items left has no item 9! So what does the code mean?!)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use assertions to test conditions that must be true if your program is *correct*.  Do not use them to test error conditions (such as memory allocation failure) that may happen despite your program being correct, because whether the asserted conditions will be tested at all is a matter of how your program is compiled.
2. It's dumb to heapify after reading each input because you don't need the data to be in heap form until after the last value is added.
3. You have a loop `while(heap->size) {...}` immediately followed by a loop `for (i = 0; i < heap->size; i++) {...}`.  If the first loop ever exits, then the second should perform zero iterations, but that's not what your output shows.  It follows that the code you posted does not correspond to the output you posted.
4. Your `deletion()` function contains a `printf()` call whose ouput is not reflected in the output you posted.  Again, it follows that the output you posted does not correspond to the code you posted.
5. Your `heapify()` function is wrong, or at least it is used wrongly.  It does not require its second argument, as it should *always* heapify however many elements are actually *in* the heap.  If that happens to correspond to the value of the most recently added element (which you assume in your calls) then that it purely coincidental.
6. Your `heapify()` function *also* contains a `printf()` whose output is not reflected in what you posted.
7. The `deletion()` function does not use the value of its first argument.
8. **The `deletion()` function has an off-by one error** here: `*(heap_array->data + (heap_array->size)) = temp`.  It should be assigning to `*(heap_array->data + (heap_array->size - 1))` (i.e. you should be performing a swap).  When you subsequently reduce the heap size by one, the position into which you just placed the erstwhile top element will no longer be part of the heap.
9. Function `deletion()` calls `heapify()` once per element (remaining) in the heap, whereas it only needs to call it once.